# While loop inside a while loop from PDO query

Tags: php, while-loop

Consider a situation where you have a mysql table **FLAGS** with a random amount of rows

```
ID  Language   Flag1               Flag2              Flag3             Flag4 
1   dutch      flanders_flag.png   dutch_flag.png 
2   french     wallonia_flag.png   french_flag.png    morocco_flag.png     
3   english    england_flag.png    ireland_flag.png   america_flag.png  scotland_flag.png
```

if i want to query these rows and put them into my html i use the while loop because i never know how much rows this table **FLAGS** has.

```
<?php
   $flagquery = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM flags");
   $flagquery->execute();
   while ($flagrow = $flagquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-6"> 
    <p><?php echo $flagrow['language']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $flagrow['flag1']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $flagrow['flag2']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $flagrow['flag3']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $flagrow['flag4']; ?></p>
  </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

But as you can see in the **FLAGS** table you don't always have 4 flags a language so i would think you have to do a while loop inside this previous while loop to echo only the flags that are present in the **FLAGS** table instead of just echo all the flags even if they are empty.

Are my thoughts right? Or what would be the best way to handle my situation?

Comment: use  isset($flagrow['flag1'])

Comment: I had that in mind to, Thank you for that same idea. But isn't there any shorter way then look if the array key isset?

Comment: isset() is a  short way .. i don't know if there is shorter :)

Comment: also  !empty()  is better ... it will return true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

Comment: just tested it and it don't work with the isset(), only with !empty or comparison with an empty string! if you query a column it will ALWAYS be SET even if it is empty.

Comment: yes i realized that and that's why i edited it :) .. also !empty check if value is null in case you allow null values in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need a second loop , you can use !empty() . it will return false if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable . it will be useful in your case and in case you allow FLAGS to have NULL value.

```
<?php
 $flagquery = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM flags");
 $flagquery->execute();
 while ($flagrow = $flagquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-6"> 
<p><?php echo $flagrow['language']; ?></p>
<?php if(!empty($flagrow['flag1'])) echo '<p>'.$flagrow['flag1'].'</p>'; ?>
 <?php if(!empty($flagrow['flag2'])) echo '<p>'.$flagrow['flag2'].'</p>'; ?>
<?php if(!empty($flagrow['flag3'])) echo '<p>'.$flagrow['flag3'].'</p>'; ?>
<?php if(!empty($flagrow['flag4'])) echo '<p>'.$flagrow['flag4'].'</p>'; ?>
</div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $flagquery = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM flags");
 $flagquery->execute();
 while ($flagrow = $flagquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-6"> 
<p><?php echo $flagrow['language']; ?></p>
<p><?php if($flagrow['flag1']!='') echo $flagrow['flag1']; ?></p>
<p><?php if($flagrow['flag2']!='') echo $flagrow['flag2']; ?></p>
<p><?php if($flagrow['flag3']!='') echo $flagrow['flag3']; ?></p>
<p><?php if($flagrow['flag4']!='') echo $flagrow['flag4']; ?></p>
</div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

check if variable is empty then it comes in if else not

Comment: i will just check if variable is empty then it comes in if else not

Comment: Post it within your answer not to me so further user get to know what you have done and why OP should go for this